# Update global Array into function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

We build an JQuery UI Datepicker at first. Later we want to update (refesh) this one. We highlighting some Dates with color an we want to change we color with this refresh. We build an array with colored dates an we want to change this array an refresh after updates this array => but the update dont work! why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dates = {'2015/5/5':'highlight_red','2015/5/6':'highlight_red'};

    function refreshCalendar (date, prozent) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var day = date.getDate();   
        var search = year+'/'+month+'/'+day;
        if (search in dates) {
            if (prozent == 100) {
                dates[search] = 'highlight_green';
            } else {
                dates[search] = 'highlight_red';
            }
        }
    }

    refreshCalendar ('2015/5/5',100);

    var erg;
    for (elem in dates) {
        erg += elem+" => "+dates[elem];
    }
    alert(erg);
</script>
```

We wand to chande die Date 2015/5/5 from red to green but the array hate this update ;-) In the control-variable erg be the same after running the funktion

Comment: try `for (search in dates)`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the date as a string, but within refreshCalendar, you are treating it as a Date object.

Try changing

```
refreshCalendar ('2015/5/5', 100);
```

to

```
refreshCalendar (new Date('2015/5/5'), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq7g87hr/1)

**Description:** added parsing of the date and initialized the erg variable so that undefined isn't returned.

```
var dates = {'2015/5/5':'highlight_red','2015/5/6':'highlight_red'};

// parse a date in yyyy/mm/dd format
function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.split('/');
    // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // Note: months are 0-based
}

function refreshCalendar (date, prozent) {
    //we have to parse out the date (real date object)
    var parsedDate = parseDate(date);
    var year = parsedDate.getFullYear();
    var month = parsedDate.getMonth();
    var day = parsedDate.getDate();   
    var search = year+'/'+month+'/'+day;
    if (search in dates) {
        if (prozent == 100) {
            dates[search] = 'highlight_green';
        } else {
            dates[search] = 'highlight_red';
        }
    }
}

refreshCalendar ('5/5/2015', 100);
// you have to initialize erg since you are using += as it will return undefined on first pass
var erg = '';
for (elem in dates) {
    erg += elem + " => " + dates[elem];
}
alert(erg);
```